# Jquery animate value inside Div

Tags: jquery

I want to animate `<p> value </p>` inside a div to animate(slideup) and fade just  like in this image

```
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bqrd.png
```

Onclick score value flies and fades out

My div is like this

```
<div id="cursoc"><p><?php echo $myresultf ?></p></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/5Lps2ohr/

```
<div id="cursoc" style="background:#98bf21;height:50px;width:100px;position:absolute;"><p>TEST</p></div>

$("#cursoc").on('click', function(e) {
        $(this).fadeOut('slow').animate({
            'bottom': '0%',
            'left': '50%',
            'top': '50%'
            }, {duration: 'fast', queue: false}, function() {
        });
})
```

Comment: need to animate only text inside `<p></p>` not whole div and upwards

Comment: look here: http://api.jquery.com/load/ jQuery load has a third parameter complete which is a callback function that is executed when the request completes. check if request is successfull then do the animation. fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/hq1ed4qu/4/

Comment: can we do onclick keep one copy and one fadeoutup?

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked nice, only thing I was thinking if a copy of text remains fixed there and one copy flies out would have been perfect